# Ошибка при попытке перейти от in-memory базы к внешней в приложении на spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Создаю приложение на spring-boot с модулями web и jpa.

У меня есть pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring-boot dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--deploy on remote tomcat-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DATABASE-->

        <!--In-memory database-->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.14.2.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>myAppFileName</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Приложение собирается в war и стартует ок.
Используется in-memory база derby

Мне нужно перейти на внешнюю базу, например mySql, 
я удалаю зависимость на derby:

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.14.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Добавляю завиcимость

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Делаю изменения в application.propeties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=111111
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

База на момент старта приложения создана, но без таблиц.

Но, при старте приложения получаю ошибку:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
>   no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or
>   Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings
>   to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no
>   profiles are currently active).
>
> 10-Sep-2018 19:43:00.935 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

mvn dependency:analyze

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:analyze (default-cli) @ SBRiskDataSvcs ---
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.7.0:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
[WARNING]    org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.7.0:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:test
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:provided
[WARNING]    io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.7.0:compile
[WARNING]    mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.46:runtime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Поменяйте на runtime.

Provided -> доступно только при компиляции. В рантайме(в жаре, который собирается) этой зависимости нет.

Comment: поправил, но к сожалению та же ошибка.

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас драйвера нет в classpath. Проверьте, что у вас драйвер действительно присутствует - mvn dependency:analyze

Comment: добавил к описанию вопроса.

Comment: возможно ли, что почему-то не подцепляется application.properties?

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov только если у вас файл называется, как в вашем вопросе "Делаю изменения в application.propeties"   -> propeties, тогда да, не цепляется.

Comment: Да! В этом все дело, спасибо!

Comment: Оформите пожалуйста как ответ.

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov ответ, в принципе, верный. Потому что с provided скоупом работать не будет.